# Como selecionar elemento no menor nivel hierarquico?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seletores

Preciso selecionar a `ul` pai do elemento `li` que esta sendo clicado. Porém como uma `li` fica dentro da outra o javascript entende que estou clicando na `li` e em todas as `li` pais.

```
<ul class="lista">
    <li class="item">
        Pai
        <ul class="lista">
            <li class="item">
                Filho
                <ul class="lista">
                    <li class="item">Neto 1</li>
                    <li class="item">Neto 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Já tentei de milhares de formas fazer a seleção da `ul`, mas acabei apagando o código e fiquei apenas com um pequeno codigo de "debug":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.item:last-child', function () {
         alert($(this).parent().length);
    });
});
```

Só quando fiz esse código que consegui visualizar q o js entende que cliquei em toda hierarquia das li e não somente na clicada, mesmo com o this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o evento (no caso, o clique) continua a se propagar através dos elementos "pais" do li clicado. Para impedir que o evento se propague, você deve utilizar a função:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Seu código deverá ficar parecido com:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.item', function (event) {
       event.stopPropagation(); 
       alert($(this).parent().length);
    });
});
```

Note que eu também retirei o pseudo-seletor :last-child. Este seletor serve para escolher sempre o último elemento-filho do elemento-pai - ou seja, o evento só seria disparado quando a pessoa clicasse no último elemento da lista.

Comment: Marquei ela correta pelo detalhe do :last-child. A primeira resposta so corrigiu isso depois. Utilizei isso no meu teste: http://doforneiro.com.br/lista1.html

Answer (score 12):

Tente usar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.item', function (e) { // retirei o :last-child
        e.stopPropagation(); // impedir a propagaço do evento pelos li's
         console.log($(this).parent()); // também pode usar .closest('ul')
    });
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/HVUan/1/)

Repare que no seu HTML um dos `<ul>` näo têm o fecho correcto:

```
        <ul>  // aqui devia ser </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Pode ler mais aqui sobre o [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation), mas no fundo impede que o evento clic se propague na árvore DOM e seja disparado em outros elementos.

O `:last-child` que tinha estava a impedir amarrar o evento ao `Neto 1`, por isso o `Filho` estava a aparecer em vez do esperado.